# cmake add_compile_definitions for specific arch for xcode

Tags: xcode, cmake

When I use `add_definitions(-DENABLE_SOMETHING)` or `add_compile_definitions(-DENABLE_SOMETHING)` in CMake to generate a Xcode Project, it will work for all archs in build setting.Just like below:[image]

How could I use add_definitions or add_compile_definitions for specific arch, like this:
[image]

Because I want to define different macros for arm64 and armv7.

I tried to append or set xcode property XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS[arch=arm64], but it will override the value generated before and only the new macro remained.
[image]

I know there is a simple way to solve this by generating xcode project for two times with different arch, like this

```
cmake . -G Xcode -DARCHS="armv7"
cmake . -G Xcode -DARCHS="arm64"
```

but I wanna to know How to fix this avoid running the command two times.

Comment: You usually do this stuff with generator expressions but I don't see any support for the architectures there. So probably you have to employ some XCode specific (and not CMake) hack or generate 2 times like you mentioned.

Comment: @ixSci Yep, I look over the doc about generator-expressions([link](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html), and didn't find solution neither. I want just use cmake to slove this rather than changing xcode project itself(like ruby xcodeproj third lib).

Comment: Maybe XCode has some capabilities to make such tweaks easily. Visual Studio, for example, has some. Alas, I don't know much about XCode so can't help with it.

Answer (score 1):

Nice question! I think you're on the right track with using the [`XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_<an-attribute>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_an-attribute.html) target property. The documentation says it accepts generator expressions, so maybe you can do something like this?

```
# early on:
set_property(
  TARGET MyApp
  PROPERTY XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS[arch=arm64]
  "$<JOIN:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:MyApp,COMPILE_DEFINITIONS>;$<TARGET_PROPERTY:MyApp,ARM64_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS>, >"
)

# later on:
if (CMAKE_GENERATOR MATCHES "Xcode")
  set_property(TARGET MyApp APPEND PROPERTY ARM64_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS ENABLE_SOMETHING)
elseif (ARCHS MATCHES "arm64")
  target_compile_definitions(MyApp PRIVATE ENABLE_SOMETHING)
endif ()
```

The idea here being that you get what the usual compile definitions would be (via the generator expression), plus the definitions added to the *custom property* `ARM64_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS ` to set XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS[arch=arm64], but I found the value is a semicolon-separated list of macros, and I didn't find a way to replace it with space using generator expression like you said.

Comment: @SkyLan - that's totally solvable... use `$<JOIN:>`. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answer my question.
I gave up looking for a pure-cmake way to solve this, and using compiler(llvm or gcc) inside arch macro to figure out which arch it is.

```
    #if defined(__aarch64__) // arm64
    #define MACRO_FOR_ARM64
    #elif defined(__arm__) // armv7
    #define MACRO_FOR_ARMV7
    #endif
```

I defined this in a common header file and it will be included by any files I want to use the macro.